# connecting to github through server permission denied (public key)

Tags: github

I am connecting to github through my ftp server.  I added the public key generated by my server then tried to connect and it is still giving me "permission denied", I attached a screenshot below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You really logged in into githubs website and copied your key into the corresponding field within your account settings?

Comment: yes, that was the easy part. wondering if it could have to do with my hosting, i am on shared hosting with dreamhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just `ssh` into githubs servers in this way. Github's SSH server allows you to use git through their servers, not shell access. You get "permission denied" because you login with user `github` instead of `git`.

After adding your SSH public key to Github (which you've done correctly), just use git with the SSH remote.

If you have not a local repo yet, just use something like:

```
git clone git@github.com:Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee.git
```

Otherwise, add a new remote to your existing git repo:

```
git add origin git@github.com:Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee.git
```

After that, push your local repo with:

```
git push
```

See also http://help.github.com/remotes/